# toast in Java, need to show the value of a textview

Tags: java, android, android-toast

i have a resulttextview that shows the result of a computation. I would like to pass the value of the this resulttextview so that it will show in a toast.

i have this code: 
    `Toast.makeText(MyCalcActivity.this,message, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()`;

but this code is showing the value of the firstnumberTxt where i type the first number to be calculated instead. :(

```
Button plusBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.plusButton1);
plusBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v) {
        EditText inputOne = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.firstnumberTxt);
        String message = inputOne.getText().toString();

        EditText inputTwo = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.secondnumberTxt);
        String message2 = inputTwo.getText().toString();


        int first = Integer.parseInt(message);
        int second = Integer.parseInt(message2);

        int sum = first + second;
        TextView resultTxt = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.resultTextview);
        resultTxt.setText("Result is  " + sum);

        Toast.makeText(MyCalcActivity.this, message, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
});
}
```

is there a way i can do this please?

Comment: Try this `Toast.makeText(MyCalcActivity.this,resultTxt.getText(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();`

Comment: You're passing `message` as the argument of the `makeText` method. How do you expect to print the value of `resultTxt`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are a starter, and just copied the code without knowing it even.
So let me get it straight forward to you.

```
     //Actual toast
        Toast.makeText(MyCalcActivity.this, message, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    // Exaplaining toast
        Toast.makeText(1, 2, 3).show();
```

- In first parameter `1`, it is the activity where the toast will be
  shown. Like you see in your code, it is `MyCalcActivity.this` which
  means it is your current activity because of the input of `this`.
- In the second parameter `2`, it is what you want to be shown. See in your code you have used `message` and from your code, we can know that message is a `string` that has the value of an `editText` you have that is called `inputOne`. But you don't want that, right? You want the value  of the `textView resultTxt` so why you are using `message`?! Replace `message` with `resultText.getText()` to get the value of the `textview` you want.
- In the last parameter, which is `3`. It is the length of the `toast message`. How long do you want it? That what it is for. In you code it is set for Long toast message which I think it is about 3 seconds. If you want a shorter one, use `Toast.LENGTH_SHORT` or a customized duration.

**So at the end,** This is your wanted code.

```
Toast.makeText(MyCalcActivity.this, resultTxt.getText().toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
.show();
```

Sorry for taking too long, but loved to help you. We all started from the bottom. But please next time search before you ask, there are a lot of similar questions and answers explaining them like this.

Answer (score 0):

Right now you're putting message into the toast, the value of "firstnumberTxt", instead of using the result that you just finished calculating.

All you need to do is use the result in the toast:

```
Toast.makeText(MyCalcActivity.this, sum, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

You can also go the long way and get what is in the TextView:

```
Toast.makeText(MyCalcActivity.this, resultText.getText().toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

Answer (score 0):

First you are calling message in the toast

```
Toast.makeText(MyCalcActivity.this, message, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

Instead to display the value of sum in the toast do,

```
Toast.makeText(MyCalcActivity.this, sum, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

Or if you want to display the value in the resultTextView, do

```
 Toast.makeText(MyCalcActivity.this, resultText.getText().toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Button plusBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.plusButton1);
plusBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v) {
        EditText inputOne = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.firstnumberTxt);
        String message = inputOne.getText().toString();

        EditText inputTwo = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.secondnumberTxt);
        String message2 = inputTwo.getText().toString();


        int first = Integer.parseInt(message);
        int second = Integer.parseInt(message2);

        int sum = first + second;
        TextView resultTxt = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.resultTextview);


        resultTxt.setText(String.valueOf(sum));

        Toast.makeText(MyCalcActivity.this,"Result is" + resultTxt, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
});
}
```

Comment: just try this you will find it simpler